# Variables bytes en Solidity: Cuando y porque usarlas

Tags: variables, solidity

estoy moviendo mis primeros pasos en Solidity, pero no acabo de entender exactamente el utilizo de las variables "bytes" y "bytes32".
He mirado no se cuantos tutoriales pero aun así no he entendido para que se usa y cuando se usan, cuales son los valores que por ejemplo admiten?
Sinceramente me está costando el tema de las variables; se que, debido a que se utilizan en la programación de smart contract, hay que utilizarlas con atención y quizás por eso que necesito entender al 100% el utilizo.
Muchas gracias